# Any better way of accessing values from database-LinqToSql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is this a Correct way of accessing  values when using Ling to SQL.I tried returning an IQueryable but got an error stating 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.' and hence converted it to a list.Can some one tell if this is ok or suggest me some other answer that you feel will be more efficient. Can i use the same implementation in all other functions that will be fetching data? Please help.

```
public List<SS_User> Login(string UserName,String Password)
        {


            using (DbContext = new DALDataContext())
            {
                IQueryable<SS_User> User = (from Users in DbContext.SS_Users
                                            where (Users.UserName == UserName && Users.Password == Password)
                                            select Users);

                return User.ToList<SS_User>();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will do the job. Note that you're making life hard for yourself by being overly specific - you could just do:

```
return (from user in dB.Users
             where {your test}
             select user).ToList();
```

But this is not *operationally* any different.

Thoughts:

- shouldn't you expect zero or one matches here? Not multiple? (FirstOrDefault / SingleOrDefault)
- how do I say this..  ***stop storing passwords***. No really; stop it. Salted hashes only.

For info the reason it didn't work when returning IQueryable is that a *query* is "deferred" - it hasn't been executed yet. If you dispose the data-context ("using") before the query is iterated (foreach, ToList etc) then the query cannot work. It would be like taking a hosepipe off the tap, then walking to the "business end", opening the nozzle, and wondering why no water.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is what i was looking for..Understood salted hashes.Can you elaborate this please:- shouldn't you expect zero or one matches here? Not multiple? (FirstOrDefault / SingleOrDefault)

Comment: @karthi personally, I would expect UserName to be a unique key - so I would never expect more than one record to come back for any username. The only questions are "is that a username at all? And does the password match?"

Comment: Yes the UserName will be unique.Password may or maynot match based on the user input should i use .FirstOrDefault() here.I checked the list in my BL using .HasAny() to check whether its empty

Comment: @Karthi .Any() is fine - that will return bool, just indicating match / no-match. If you want the actual user record (to get more details etc) then FirstOrDefault would be ideal.

Comment: need a help! Can i use  DbContext = new DALDataContext() without wrapping them inside using().Will the instance automatically get disposed? or should i do it in some other way?

Comment: @karthi it would be better to use `using`, especially if the data-context owns the connection

Comment: @ Marc Gravell I was trying to get some data as queryable to bind to a listview and the context was getting disposed hence did by removing the using ().Seems i need to find another way .Thanks for your reply Marc